# Cannot get the string result from image C# Windows Form

Tags: c#

It's always stop at the end of RawFormat, what did I do wrong?

```
 private void genImgBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {

            Image gambar = pictureBox1.Image;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                gambar.Save(ms,gambar.RawFormat);
                byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
                qrtext.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Silahkan pilih gambar terlebih dahulu");
        }

    }
```

The program stops and asks for not giving null value. I don't know what should I do to resolve this.

Comment: It worked fine for me. What is the exact exception you're getting and on which line?

Comment: @Volkan Paksoy 21 This line
"gambar.Save(ms,gambar.RawFormat);"

when I run the program it will stop there and asks for value.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce the problem. I don't quite understand what it is asking. There is nothing to indicate that kind of thing in the code you posted. Or maybe I'm missing something...